# Digitação na TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Estou fazendo um projeto no visual studio e preciso de ajuda. Gostaria de saber se tem como ou como faz para fazer com que quando eu digite na textbox,isso que eu digitei comece pela frente independente da posição do cursor ou que ele va meio que excluindo até chegar na frente.A textbox seria de telefone mais ou menos assim:(__)____-____.

Comment: Vc quer usar uma mascara no campo é isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `Enter` do `MaskedTextBox` que vai ser disparado sempre que o usuário clicar no componente e dentro dele usar o método `Select`, desta forma:

No método abaixo, também é validado se o TextBox está vazio para colocar o cursor no início.

Para usar desta forma, você precisa trocar a propriedade `TextMaskFormat` para `ExcludePromptAndLiterals`. - Isso vai fazer com que a propriedade `Text` do `TextBox` contenha apenas o texto digitado pelo usuário.

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txtbox = (MaskedTextBox)sender;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text))
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => txtbox.Select(0, 0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho que adicionar alguma referência? Porque algumas palavras não mudaram a cor.

Comment: Não. O que é que "não mudou a cor"?

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace, Text, BeginInvoke, Select.

Comment: E não deu certo.

Comment: Tem certeza que não escreveu algo errado?

Comment: Arrumei, era um erro meu, vlw.

Comment: Certo, você pode marcar a resposta como correta se ela te ajudou clicando no **✓** abaixo das setas para votar ***=)***.